# In Scala, How to reference the ClassTag of implemented abstract type in all subclasses?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, abstract-type

If I have 1 trait and 2 objects:

```
trait MyClass {
  type T <: MyClass

  def foo(): ClassTag[T] = {...}
}

object ChildClass1 extends MyClass {
   type T = String
}

object ChildClass2 extends MyClass {
   type T = Option[String]
}
```

is it possible to implement foo() in MyClass, such that ChildClass1.foo() yields ClassTag[String], and ChildClass2.foo() yields ClassTag[Option].

If not, what's the easiest way to bypass it? It should be noted that the implementation of T may be inner classes/objects, so hacking reflection may have some side effects.

Comment: Why do you need reflection in the first place? In Scala, there is usually a way around it.

Comment: Yes, though a more verbose and unnecessary way to repeat what the compiler should already know

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a dirty and impaired answer, please advice me if you have any better idea:

```
  lazy val mf: ClassTag[T] = {

    val clazz = this.getClass
    val name = clazz.getName
    val modifiedName = name + "T"
    val reprClazz = Utils.classForName(modifiedName)

    Manifest.classType(reprClazz)
  }
```

it only works if the subclass is a singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's possible that I don't completely understand your goal, but from what I can see, you are trying to create a trait with an upper bound type, and you also want to be able to get the type at runtime, correct?

So let's assume you have a `Foo` trait:

```
class MyClass // not important

trait Foo[T <: MyClass] {
  def foo: ClassTag[T]
}
```

If you want an object implementation, the solution is trivial, since you know the type at compile time:

```
class MyClassSubclass extends MyClass // also not important

object FooObject extends Foo[MyClassSubclass] {
  def foo: ClassTag[MyClassSubclass] = ClassTag(classOf[MyClassSubclass])
}
```

But if you want a class, then you can solve the problem with the `implicitly` + context bound combo in a pretty readable way:

```
class FooImpl[T <: MyClass : ClassTag] extends Foo[T] {
  def foo: ClassTag[T] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
}
```

Comment: That looks good but in my implementation the def foo: ClassTag can be omitted. Simplicity is always desirable